# NSFileProtection and accessing core data in background fetch

Tags: ios

I am using core data in my application and have already set the persistent store coordinator file protection to `NSFileProtectionComplete`.
I also have background fetch enabled and the app downloads and stores Data to core Data in background fetch. Now i was wondering will the core data get updated in background fetch when the device is locked since `NSFileProtectionComplete` is set?

Answer (score 0):

No. Once you set NSFileProtectionComplete to the core data file, you can't access core data file while app is in background.
You will have to find other way to update core data file.

Comment: https://proton.me/blog/ios-security-model says it can: The data protection class for files is set as NSFileProtectionComplete in app entitlements with default exceptions for CoreData (which includes messages, attachments, folders, contacts, etc.) and UserDefaults (which includes user account information and settings) files, which the app needs to be able to access in the background and when the device is locked.